# Room Database force OnCreate callback

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm developing an application with RoomDatabase that needs to pre-populate its data; I already managed to do it by adding the `onCreate()` callback, but it gets called only when accessing the database the first time (like calling one of the Daos functions).

Is there any way to force the database creation without doing any read or write operation?

That's my code, `MyDatabase.get()` is called in `App.onCreate()`

```
@Database(entities = {Entity1.class, Entity2.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = true)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static MyDatabase sInstance;

    public synchronized static TaxCodeDatabase get(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = buildDatabase(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private static MyCodeDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                MyCodeDatabase.class,
                "my-database")
                .addCallback(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        sInstance.preFillData(context);
                      });
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    public abstract Entity1Dao entity2Dao();

    public abstract Entity2Dao entity1Dao();

    /**
     * Populates the database with a series of initial data
     *
     * @param aContext
     */
    public void prePopulateData(Context aContext) {
        //Populate database here
    }
```

Comment: Why not create a subclass of `Application` and call your `MyDatabase` singleton in that part? Take note onCreate is only called once not unless you delete your database.

Comment: Because is in a separated module and I don't want to have another instance elsewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to force the database creation without doing any read or write operation?

No, sorry.

There is nothing stopping you from copying the pre-populated database into position before invoking Room, though. You would need to ensure that the pre-populated database has Room's metadata in it (e.g., by creating that database using Room itself).

Comment: Thanks it's as I guessed so. I'll try with your suggestion

Comment: @CommonsWare Wouldn't his code with super.onCreate(db); sInstance.preFillData(context); trigger recursive calls of onCreate()? The only ways to avoid this is either to: 1)call sInstance.preFillData(context) from separate thread or (2)to use raw SQL queries on db object like in your book (but we lose type safety of Room). Is it really so or you have better proposal for pre-populating

Comment: @Ewoks: A separate thread would be seriously dangerous here. Instead, you could do `preFillData()` outside the callback, but inside `buildDatabase()`, where `preFillData()` also checks for whether the data has been loaded previously or not.

Answer (score 25):

It's took me a while to understand why a Room database is not populated with initial data after invoking `.build()` on a database builder.

As for me, it's really counter-intuitive that migrations and callbacks are triggered only on real read/write operation. Actually the issue caused by the reason that Room use `class RoomOpenHelper` which, as mentioned in documentation:

> An open helper that holds a reference to the configuration until the database is opened.

As the result, configuration and all callbacks stored in the instance of `RoomOpenHelper` class while Sqlite's `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which actually performs database migrations, not created (lazy class loading in Java).

To overcome this behavior, any operation which cause `getWritableDatabase()` should be performed. I ended up with the following approach:

```
RoomDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            ...)
            .build();

  // and then
db.beginTransaction()
db.endTransaction()

  // or query a dummy select statement
db.query("select 1", null)

return db
```

After that the database will be created and populated with initial data.

Comment: how to do that with populated  database in asset force room to delete previous db and then recreate  it from asset bcz fallbackToDestructiveMigration do that but with empty db i want to recreate it and then copy database tables from asset thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[Room version 2.2.0 (October 2019)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3) introduced built-in methods for database's pre-population:

1. From the prepackaged database file (*.db) that you should place inside `assets/` directory.
2. From the prepackaged database file (*.db) that you should place somewhere except `assets/` directory.

For more details you can read [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).

For getting answer - how to prepare prepackaged database you can read [this article in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778041/what-format-should-the-db-file-take-in-a-call-to-room-createfromassetinitia).