# What format should the `.db` file take in a call to Room.createFromAsset("initialData.db")?

Tags: android, android-room

### Scenario

I am attempting to pre-populate a Room database with a few entries. The documentation on the api call is clear ([developer.android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#kotlin)), and I've read a good blog ([Medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/packing-the-room-pre-populate-your-database-with-this-one-method-333ae190e680)), but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax/format for the actual prepackaged database file (`developmentData.db` in the example below). I cannot find any documentation anywhere I've searched.

```
Room
  .databaseBuilder(
      context.applicationContext, 
      MyDatabase::class.java, 
      "my_database")
  .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
  .createFromAsset("database/developmentData.db")
  .build()
```

### Thoughts

I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema) for exporting the schema. Here is what came out of that process, for reference. In this case, I'm just creating a dummy object for the sake of asking my question here.

```
{
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "database": {
    "version": 1,
    "identityHash": "0ad43a6714902eedbb90c1f77ab1ffcb",
    "entities": [
      {
        "tableName": "library_table",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`libraryId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `description` TEXT NOT NULL)",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "libraryId",
            "columnName": "libraryId",
            "affinity": "INTEGER",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "title",
            "columnName": "title",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": true
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "description",
            "columnName": "description",
            "affinity": "TEXT",
            "notNull": true
          }
        ],
        "primaryKey": {
          "columnNames": [
            "libraryId"
          ],
          "autoGenerate": true
        },
        "indices": [],
        "foreignKeys": []
      }
    ],
    "setupQueries": [
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)",
      "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, \"0ad43a6714902eedbb90c1f77ab1ffcb\")"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are the current contents of my `developmentData.db`, but it fails validation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `library_table` (
`libraryId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
`title` TEXT NOT NULL,
`description` TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `library_table` (title, description) VALUES ("Library 1", "A whopping amazing library!");
INSERT INTO `library_table` (title, description) VALUES ("Library the Second", "A smashing library indeed!");
INSERT INTO `library_table` (title, description) VALUES ("Thou Third Library", "Quite possibly the most amazing library ever.");
INSERT INTO `library_table` (title, description) VALUES ("Ye Olde Fouthe Librarye", "So many profound thoughts in here.");
```

Here is the error. It's not encrypted, so this must be an issue with the syntax.
`E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database`

### Question

What format should the `.db` file that is referenced in the call to `createFromAsset()` take? If there is existing documentation somewhere, I would be glad for the reference.

Comment: It should be a SQLite database, and I think it may need to be one prepared by Room itself. "but it fails validation" -- can you provide details?

Comment: Good call for detail, thanks. Just added that to the question.

Comment: That error suggests that the database file itself is corrupt that Room is trying to open. "Here are the current contents of my developmentData.db" -- do you mean that literally, that `developmentData.db` is an text file with that text? If so, try a SQLite database, not a SQL script. For example, copy a database off of a device after you have had Room create one (sans `createFromAsset()`).

Comment: Ah... I was on the wrong track completely. I had in my mind something like the data.sql that Spring can execute to prepopulate a database. You're correct, and that solved the issue. I'll try to give a more complete answer below, but @CommonsWare should get the credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely server-side database systems (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.), when closed, a SQLite database is a single file. `createFromAsset()` is expecting that sort of file, not a SQL script.

So, what I have usually done is:

- Have the app create an empty database on a device using Room's schema, using standard Room stuff
- Copy that database off the device (e.g., using Device File Explorer in Android Studio)
- Use SQL Browser or `sqlite3` or other tools to add data to my app's tables

That way, I'm guaranteed that the database will have the right structure and Room's metadata.

Comment: This answer is more concise, and the idea of copying the db off the device rather than examining the json is simpler than what I explained in my own answer. I would recommend others to follow this pattern.

Answer (score 5):

The solution here was to create an actual SQLite database binary, instead of the series of SQL statements I have above, and use that file. The process to create this was not immediately apparent from the documentation, so I'll explain it here in case someone else needs to be pointed in the right direction. @CommonsWare should get credit for this answer, as the one who pointed me in the correct direction.

### Export the schema for the Room database in the app.

There is good documentation for this step [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema). In short, I needed to add this annotation to my RoomDatabase class. Take note of the `exportSchema = true` part. This causes a Gradle build to drop a .json file in `app/schemas` directory.

```
@Database(entities = [Library::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

That json file contains `tableName` and `createSql` key:value pairs that I used in the next step. It looks like this:

```
"tableName": "library_table",
"createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`libraryId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `description` TEXT NOT NULL)",
```

### Create the SQLite binary file

I then made use of a free application called [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to actually create the .db binary that I needed, with reference to the .json mentioned above. Once I added a few records into it and saved, the data pre-populated without any issue.

### Place the binary in the correct directory

One final note, that I didn't find immediately obvious from the documentation: The call to `createFromAsset()` looks, by default, in the `/assets` directory. This directory needs to be INSIDE the desired source set. So, for example, I placed my .db binary here:
`<project-root>/app/src/main/assets/initialData.db`

Comment: Out of curiosity... did you add `room_master_table` to your database, or just your own tables? I have not tried doing it without that table and its contents from the `setupQueries` in the JSON, but it would be more convenient if we didn't necessarily need to worry about that for the `createFromAsset()` path.

Comment: @humbleDev Yes, if you've mentioned json file, you should include in your answer another useful section "setupQueries" with room_master_table code for creation

Comment: I actually did not add that section of the json file to the SQLite database I created and passed into the createFromAsset() call. The call still succeeded, though, and loaded the data as expected.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Apologies for the delayed comment here, but I attempted to use the database from my device to create some initial data, and found that there is no room_master_table present in it when I do so. Do you find one in the databases you pull off the device?

Comment: @humbleDev: If the database was created by Room, yes.

Comment: It worked for me by creating a new database file in DB Browser, then using your answer to create the table using the exported schema and its create table command, and after that I ran my SQL insert queries to populate it with data.