# How to pre-populate Room database at first run?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am creating an android app in java that uses room SQLite to store data.
The app have two  tables:

- CoursesTable
- StudentsTable

I want to add default values for `course_name` entity so  when the user open the app find the courses.

For example :

**Math - Sport - Art - Music**

```
@Entity
public class CoursesTable {
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   int course_id;
   String course_name;
}
```

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/pre-populate-room-database-6920f9acc870

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To insert data on first run / after db creation, you can use `RoomDatabase.Callback`.

> You can run scripts after database is created or run every time
>   database is opened using RoomDatabase.Callback, this class is
>   available in the latest version of the Room library.
>
> You need to implement onCreate and onOpen method of
>   RoomDatabase.Callback and add it to RoomDatabase.Builder as shown
>   below.

```java
yourDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, YourDatabase.class, "your db")
    .addCallback(rdc)
    .build();

RoomDatabase.Callback rdc = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    public void onCreate (SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        // ADD YOUR "Math - Sport - Art - Music" here
    }
    public void onOpen (SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        // do something every time database is open
    }
};
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/pre-populate-room-database-6920f9acc870) and detailed information about the callbacks [here](https://medium.com/@srinuraop/database-create-and-open-callbacks-in-room-7ca98c3286ab)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206963/4370279)