# Pre-populating Room database with Hilt without creating an extra instance of the database

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am trying to ensure that my database always contains an initial row. I read through [How to populate Android Room database table on first run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697418/how-to-populate-android-room-database-table-on-first-run) and the main thing that I'm running into is that I have no instance to access (or I don't know how to access it?) using Hilt when I'm creating the database. If I try re-using the `provideDatabase` Hilt method I've written, it results in SQLite Database Leaks (presumably because there's no one around to close the database using those spawned instances). Here's my code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): GameDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, GameDatabase::class.java, GameDatabase.GAME_DB_NAME)
            .addCallback(
                object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        // Initialize the database with the first game
                        ioThread {
                            provideDatabase(context).gameDao().createNewGame(Game())
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onOpen(db) 

                        // Ensure there is always one game in the database
                        // This will capture the case of the app storage
                        // being cleared
                        // THIS results in an instance being created that can't be closed - causing DB leaks!
                        ioThread {
                            val gameDao = provideDatabase(context).gameDao()

                            if (gameDao.gameCount() == 0) {
                                gameDao.createNewGame(Game())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideGameDao(database: GameDatabase): GameDao {
        return database.gameDao()
    }
}
```

So, how do I get a hold of my DAO to do the initialization? Do I need to just manually craft an insert statement in SQL and call it on the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `provideDatabase` method always creates a new instance whenever it is called: Dagger makes it a singleton by only calling that method once.  The only way to get the singleton `GameDatabase` instance managed by `ApplicationComponent` is to request it as a dependency.  Since `GameDatabase` will need to depend on itself via `GameDao`, this is a circular dependency.

To resolve a circular dependency in Dagger, you can depend on a [`Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) or [`Lazy`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html):

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context, gameDaoProvider: Provider<GameDao>): GameDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, GameDatabase::class.java, GameDatabase.GAME_DB_NAME)
            .addCallback(
                object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        // Initialize the database with the first game
                        ioThread {
                            gameDaoProvider.get().createNewGame(Game())
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onOpen(db) 

                        // Ensure there is always one game in the database
                        // This will capture the case of the app storage
                        // being cleared
                        // This uses the existing instance, so the DB won't leak
                        ioThread {
                            val gameDao = gameDaoProvider.get()

                            if (gameDao.gameCount() == 0) {
                                gameDao.createNewGame(Game())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).build()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. No more SQLiteDatabase ugly warnings about memory leaks! Appreciate the speedy assistance.

Comment: Crahes with an error : In recursive manner pointing at daoprovider.get()

Answer (score 1):

There's one problem:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideGameDao(database: GameDatabase): GameDao {
    return database.gameDao()
}
```

should be:

```
@Provides
fun provideGameDao(database: GameDatabase): GameDao {
    return database.gameDao()
}
```